# TMDB PHP result array

Tags: php, themoviedb-api

I use code in PHP for get info about season. How I can get result in array??
Thanks.

[Doc TMDB](https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/tv-seasons/get-tv-season-details)

```
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/tv/xxx/season/xxx?language=en-US&api_key=xxx",

$response = curl_exec($curl);
 echo $response;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your expected result seems to be a JSON-object, according to the documentation you linked - so `echo` won't work.
Use `var_dump(json_decode($response));` to see the result.

If you want to work with the JSON-object in PHP you will have to "cast" it to a PHP-object:

```
$newObject = json_decode($response);
```

You can than access the objects properties in PHP like so:

```
echo $newObject->id;
echo $newObject->name;
```

etc..
See the PHP documentation on this topic here: [PHP - json-decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: This is what I need. Thank you very much. I'm very happy)))

Comment: @DavidBrown glad i could help. Would be cool if you mark the answer as accepted, if it solved your problem. Thanks!